# How to set up mailing profile on a Express Edition of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to have a mailer profile on SQL Server Management Studio without "Database Mail"?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio ***IS*** the management tools - so this question is anything but clear.....

Comment: Express edition doesn't have "Database Mail" in management folder its clear as day light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/) is a blog that details the process.

Below is a rough copy of the blog contents to future-proof this answer.

1. Enable the database mail stored procs:

   ```
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   ```
2. Create the sysmail account with `sysmail_add_account_sp`:

   ```
   EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
   @account_name = 'MailTest',
   @description = 'Sent Mail using MSDB',
   @email_address = 'umashankar@queryingsql.com',
   @display_name = 'umashankar',
   @username='umashankar@queryingsql.com',
   @password='password',
   @mailserver_name = 'mail.queryingsql.com'
   ```
3. Create the database profile with `sysmail_add_profile_sp`:

   ```
   EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
   @profile_name = 'MailTest',
   @description = 'Profile used to send mail'
   ```
4. Map the account to the profile with `sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp`:

   ```
   EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
   @profile_name = 'MailTest',
   @account_name = 'MailTest',
   @sequence_number = 1
   ```
5. Grant a database principal (database user or role) to use the database profile:

   ```
   EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
   @profile_name = 'MailTest',
   @principal_name = 'public',
   @is_default = 1 ;

   --A principal_name of 'public' makes this profile a public profile, granting access to all principals in the database.
   ```
6. Test with `sp_send_dbmail`:

   ```
   exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
   @profile_name = 'MailTest', 
   @recipients = 'receiver@queryingsql.com', 
   @subject = 'Mail Test', 
   @body = 'Mail Sent Successfully', 
   @body_format = 'text'
   ```

You should also look up the MSDN documentation for each stored procedure to be sure you're configuring your system correctly.

Comment: I'm a rookie so i can't mark your answer as correct for now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can set it up using the stored procs in MSDB. I have not tried this, but you might want to give it a shot.

Look at...

```
sysmail_add_account_sp
```

... and it's related stored procs.

[sysmail_add_account_sp MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182804.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

By default the SQL Express doesn't support database mail configuration through a GUI wizard, nevertheless it is possible to configure it through scripts.

These [detailed instructions](http://blog.krzysztofjakobczyk.pl/?p=34) guide you.